# facebook integration Key Hash error in release build Android

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

facebook integration working perfect with debug android apk but its problem with release build apk KEY hash error. Please let me know, how can i will be fix.[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In key hash put both debug key hash and release key hash.

Comment: How can generate release key?

Comment: copy that keyhash from cmd prompt

Comment: release key generate based on your keystore file

Comment: This is way to generate release keyhash ok...

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias **aliasname**
     -keystore "C:\Users\-----path----\.android\release.keystore" |"C:\openssl\bin\opens
    sl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64


Enter keystore password:  **keystore password**
nWs908k6K4sfoIvWyuioklp=

Comment: Means release.keystore need to generate not use default?  right? .jks is keystore

Comment: .jks is key store

Comment: yeah... that is keystore file

Comment: Ok then i am right. but this key also not working. Whats wrong now.

Comment: can you share your keystore file and password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141900/discussion-between-srinivas-keerthiprakasam-and-rahul-wadhai).

Answer (score 0):

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias **aliasname**
     -keystore "C:\Users\-----path----\.android\release.keystore" |"C:\openssl\bin\opens
    sl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64


Enter keystore password:  **keystore password**
nWs908k6K4sfoIvWyuioklp=
```

https://www.openssl.org/source/
Need a openssl. Without openssl you cannot generate release hash key

Comment: What is aliasname ? its a sign key Alies ?

Comment: yes.... after generating the keyhash include in developers.facebook.com

Comment: release.keystore is  "xxx.jks " file ?

Comment: Thanks, but i have try same way but Key Hash not working means its return error

Comment: After generating the release keyhash put in developers.facebook.com

Comment: Invalid key hash.The key hash nWs908k6K4sfoIvWyuioklp= does not match any stored key hashes.  but this error key and generated key are different.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias **aliasname**
     -keystore "C:\Users\-----path----\.android\release.keystore" |"C:\openssl\bin\opens
    sl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
 Use this code and run in your command promp fill up your data. here i mention dummy data.

Comment: I have set generated key to this link https://developers.facebook.com/apps/35566215902345677

Comment: Yes i have generated through this but also problem with release build

Comment: how to generate \key hash

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias myalise -keystore "C:\Users\ADMIN\.android\mykeystore.jks" | "C:\Users\ADMIN\abc\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\ADMIN\abc\bin\openssl.exe" base64

Comment: after run this what eror u got

Comment: After generated its working fine for debug apk, but its problem with release build apk "  
Invalid key hash.The key hash nWs908k6K4sfoIvWyuioklp= does not match any stored key hashes. but this error key and generated key are different. "

Comment: Yes I have used generated key.

Comment: But i could not understand whats wrong with release build.

Comment: can u share your cmd prompt screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141898/discussion-between-rahul-wadhai-and-srinivas-keerthiprakasam).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do it like in cmd prompt......

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\admin\.android\debug.keystore" |"C:\openssl\bin\opens
sl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: after giving password you will get one key know. copy that key put in developers.facebook.com in your project

Comment: i know sir, but its problem with release apk.

Comment: signed apk is generate or not